# Common sizes of intersections

Tags: co.combinatorics

I'm trying to come up with the largest family of sets that obeys the following properties:

Consider $X = \{1,\dots,n\}$ and take $\mathcal{F} \subset 2^X$ such that for any three subsets $A,B,C \in \mathcal{F}$ we have that (at least) two of the numbers $|A \cap B|, |B \cap C|, |A \cap C|$ are the same size.

There is a trivial example here, $\{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\},\dots$ which gives a family $\mathcal{F}$ of size $n$, but I don't see how to do better (I've tried using modular arithmetic, which doesn't seem to help all that much.)

In this problem it doesn't particularly matter (to me at least) what $n$ is, eg, for the modular arithmetic way I was trying I set $n = L^2$ for some integer.

So, my question is as follows, is there a better choice for $\mathcal{F}$, eg, one that is larger than the trivial?

Comment: The most trivial one is the family of all singletons. It has the same $\ n\ $ members.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider $\ \binom A2\ $ for an arbitrary finite set $\ A.\ $ Then you get a proper family with $\ \binom n2\ $ members for $\ n:=|A|.\ $ You get an improvement for every $\ n>3$.

**EDIT:**   Let me coin the name *"Three Is a Crowd"* (or *TIsC* for short) for the families introduced in the ***Question*** by **James Kilbane**. Now thanks to the comments let me record certain improvements:

- **The Masked Avenger** has proposed to add the whole set $\ A,\ $ and the empty set too--let's be greedy. Thus the enlarged Three Is a Crowd family looks like this:

$$ \binom A2\cup\{A\,\ \emptyset\} $$

for a new record $\ \binom n2+2\ $ for $\ n=|A|$.

- **Tony Huynh** has successfully added the singletons (and the empty set). This gives the following increased Three Is a Crowd family:

$$\binom{A}{2} \cup \binom A 1 \cup \binom A 0$$

for a new record $\ \binom {n+1}2$.

- The semi-dual example is just as good:

$$\binom A{n-2}\cup\binom A{n-1}\cup\{\emptyset\}$$

for $\ n:=|A|.\ $ We get $\ \binom {n+1}2\ $ different members again.

> It'd be nice to find the **maximum**.

Comment: Why not add A to it for a slightly larger set?  Not to mention the empty set.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger -- I've answered the Question *exactly*, and without going into extra trivialities--the originator didn't bother with the empty set (and he could); thus there was an  implied assumption that the sets should be non-empty (either way). My answer is the *simplest* so far. I followed the Kazimierz Kuratowski's principle: first of all an example should be as simple as possible.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger -- you're welcome to add another, more advanced and sharper result (Especially that a simple answer is already present, making sense to develop the idea further).

Comment: You can also add all the singleton sets (and the empty set) to your solution.  This gives $\binom{n}{2}+n+1$ sets.

Comment: @TonyHuynh -- with your approval, I'd add an extra EDIT note, which would state your addition (and I'd mention TMA too  :-).

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński Sure, that's fine by me.  By the way, nice answer, I already +1ed you.

Comment: Huh. I meant singletons.  I guess I should have said it.  Oh well, just add A the whole set to Tony's example.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger -- I can read only what you write, I cannot read your mind :-) In general, I wish that you and many other OM users would write in a way which would be easier for me to understand without so-to-speak hacking into their mind. But I understand that often it may not seem worth the effort to them.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger You cannot add the whole set $A$ to my example since the of sets $\{1\}, \{2,3\}$ and $A$ have pairwise intersection sizes of $0, 1$, and $2$.

Comment: @Tony.  Indeed.  I withdraw the suggestion of  "adding A".

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions: I'm now interested to see what the maximum possible number is, I might go away and try and find out.